# Receiving memory warning after saving 80 ekevents

Tags: ios, objective-c, ekevent, ekeventstore

```
- (void)syncWithCalendar
{

    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [util readPListData];  
    NSMutableArray *courses = [util getCourses];  
    __block NSMutableArray *lessons;   
    __block NSMutableDictionary *lesson;    
    NSString *studentID = [util getProgramDetails].studentId;  
    NSString *programName = [util getProgramDetails].programName;

    __block NSString *startDateString = @"", *endDateString = @"";

    NSDateFormatter *formatter;  
    formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];  
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];  
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];  

    NSString *currentDateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ 09:00:00", [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];  
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

    NSDate *currentDate = [formatter dateFromString:currentDateString];

    self.eventstore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

   [self.eventstore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)  
    {  
        if (granted) {  

            NSLog(@"calendar access granted");

            for (int i=0; i<[courses count]; i++)
            {
                lessons = [[courses objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"lessons"];
                for (int j=0; j<[lessons count]; j++)
                {
                    lesson = [lessons objectAtIndex:j];
                    NSString *title = nil;
                    title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@-Complete %@ lesson",studentID,programName,[lesson objectForKey:@"lesson-name"]];

                    startDateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [lesson objectForKey:@"exam-date"], @"09:00:00"];
                        endDateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [lesson objectForKey:@"exam-date"], @"18:00:00"];

                    if (!([startDateString isEqualToString:@""] && [endDateString isEqualToString:@""]))
                    {
                        EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:self.eventstore];
                        event.title=title;
                        event.startDate = [formatter dateFromString:startDateString];
                        event.endDate = [formatter dateFromString:endDateString];

                        event.allDay = NO;

                        [event setCalendar:[self.eventstore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];


                       NSError *err = nil;
             [self.eventstore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];
           //[self.eventstore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
                            if (err) {
                                NSLog(@"event not saved .. error = %@",err);
                            } else {
                                NSLog(@"event added successfully");
                            }       
                    }
                } // lessons for loop
            } // courses for loop

        } else {
            NSLog(@"Access not granted");
        }
    }];

    [self.eventstore release];  
    [formatter release];
}
```

After events gets successfully added it shows:

> "Received Memory Warning. Terminating in response to SpringBoard's termination"

and the app terminates. This is happening in iOS 7 device. I haven't checked it yet in iOS 6 and below. The code works fine if there are only a few events saved (30 or less) but it shows memory issue for 80 events or more on saving.

Comment: Why aren't you using ARC? Where in your code are you creating something and not releasing it? Did you use Instruments?

Comment: I guess I am releasing everything in my code. Let me try and switch my code to ARC.

Comment: I tried in ARC also but it is still showing the same issue ...

Comment: And you used Instruments to see what it created and when, but not destroyed?

Comment: yeah I am trying but I am new to instruments so don't exactly know how to detect the line of code where memory leak occurs .... I can see the flag in my instruments that show low memory warning but I am not able to understand where exactly is the issue in code ...

Comment: look at live bytes. Drill into it. Find the large amount of data. Look at the associated code (⌘E).

Answer (score 6):

Finally I found the answer to my question. I would like to share my solution so that it can help others ....

I was specially getting the crash in iOS 7 and it was because of the below line

// wrong
[self.eventstore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];

The correct way to save event: (Note: I didn't require event identifier for my case)
// correct
[self.eventstore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:NO error:&err];
and then use
[self.eventstore commit:NULL]

after all the events are saved. 
This stopped the crash in my case.

Comment: I had tried saveEvent:span:error: and assumed that it was not doing the commit. I was wrong. You must use the Commit:NO flag as you say

Answer (score 1):

Switching to ARC may solve the problem with memory but problems may still occur with large amount of data.
Try using @autorelease pools inside for loop as in example

```
for (int i=0; i<[courses count]; i++)
            {
@autoreleasepool {
                lessons = [[courses objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"lessons"];
                for (int j=0; j<[lessons count]; j++)
                {
                    lesson = [lessons objectAtIndex:j];
                    NSString *title = nil;
                    title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@-Complete %@ lesson",studentID,programName,[lesson objectForKey:@"lesson-name"]];

                    startDateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [lesson objectForKey:@"exam-date"], @"09:00:00"];
                        endDateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [lesson objectForKey:@"exam-date"], @"18:00:00"];

                    if (!([startDateString isEqualToString:@""] && [endDateString isEqualToString:@""]))
                    {
                        EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:self.eventstore];
                        event.title=title;
                        event.startDate = [formatter dateFromString:startDateString];
                        event.endDate = [formatter dateFromString:endDateString];

                        event.allDay = NO;

                        [event setCalendar:[self.eventstore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];


                       NSError *err = nil;
             [self.eventstore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];
           //[self.eventstore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
                            if (err) {
                                NSLog(@"event not saved .. error = %@",err);
                            } else {
                                NSLog(@"event added successfully");
                            }       
                    }
                } // lessons for loop
}//autoreleasepool
            } // courses for loop
```

This way each for loop step will release all autorelease objects.

Comment: I tried autoreleasepool but I am still getting the issue "Terminating in response to SpringBoard's termination."

Comment: Have you tried it on iOS 6?
Have a look at this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/instruments-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-debug-memory-leaks where using Instruments is explained. This way you can try to debug possible leaks.

Comment: The code is working fine in iOS 6. It is crashing in iOS 7. What should I do ?

Comment: Did you use Instruments to find where is memory leak happening? It's obvious that you need to release unused memory, just before that you need to locate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

@upendar I also have same scenario but i am split into small chunks, I.E. Like if you have 80 events to sync take 20-20 and pause 2-5sec. between them. 
`autoreleasepool` is good to use, But it Calendar took too much memory to execute. It will take more then 100% some time.

I bared with this issue. Really interesting one!!!